# Can't open .xml file in read mode Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, cascade, haar-classifier

```
import cv2

data = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

returns:

```
Can't open file: 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml' in read mode
```

I'm new to all this and not quite sure what this error means.

Tried to open `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml`

using `cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'`)

I've looked everywhere.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Is such a file present in the current working directory?

Comment: yes. haarcascade_frontalface_.xml is present in the directory

Answer (score 0):

Give the full path of the xml and it will work.

Comment: "as shown below" -- there's only an empty gray box below, is that intentional?

Comment: trained_face_data = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'/My_Workspace/venv/lib/python/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml') doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Solved.  Directly copied path of xml and it indeed worked.